# Can having a LIMIT on DELETE degrade performance dramatically?

Tags: mysql, performance, delete, limits, query-performance

I have a database project in `php` and `mysql`.  For, hopefully redundant, data security I added a `LIMIT 1` to the `delete($uniqueID)` php function we use.

Nobody cared because records really aren't supposed to be deleted often from this database.  However we recently got a massive jump in the response time for this server.  By massive I mean approximately four times worse than our previous worst heavy load performance.

The culprit seems to be a series of 100 individual `DELETE` statements from a small table, about 7 columns and 150 records.  This doesn't seem right.  Is it possible that this newly added `LIMIT 1` is obliterating performance?

I don't think so, but the data logging I have suggest that it is.

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not in this case.

The evidence pointing towards a `DELETE ... LIMIT 1` was real, but not entirely accurate.  The real issue here was a `PHP` script that called hundreds of unnecessary queries in order to execute the suspected `DELETE ... LIMIT 1` query.

Using MySQL's log all queried on a test environment lead to the solution to this problem.